# Julia: Check if first Letter in String Is Lowercase preferred syntax

Tags: regex, julia, lowercase

Let's say I have a string `x="1. this should be capitalized"`

Right now if I want to check if the first letter is capitalized

```
s = "1. (t)his should be capitalized"
s2 = match(r"^.*?([a-zA-Z])", s).captures[1]
@show all(islowercase, s2)
# true
```

If I do `islowercase(s2)` I get a `MethodError`. Though I could also do `@show uppercasefirst(s2) != s2` but this seems unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: `islowercase(s2[1])` seems the cleanest answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noted, `islowercase` works with individual characters, and not strings. To extract the first character from the regex match string you can use `first`:

```
julia> s = "1. (t)his should be capitalized";

julia> s2 = match(r"^.*?([a-zA-Z])", s).captures[1]
"t"

julia> islowercase(first(s2))
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively do the following:

```
 s = "1. (t)his should be capitalized";
 s2 = s[findfirst(r"[:alpha]", s)[1]]
 islowercase(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex. Just use `islowercase` on your string directly (via splatting and broadcasting), and get the index of the first true result.

```
findfirst(  islowercase.([ x... ])  )
```

If your strings do not have consistent syntax, you could also check if it is a letter.

```
findfirst( islowercase.( [ x... ] ) .& isletter.( [ x... ] ) )
```

Comment: Splatting can be pretty expensive (especially twice.) wouldn't `collect` be better, or (

Comment: doesn't `islowercase.` work directly on the string. Or perhaps `findfirst(islowercase, x)`. (Posting from my phone, so can't check it).

Comment: @DNF I thought it would too, but turns out it's only got a single `islowercase(c::AbstractChar)` method. I suppose `collect` or a `generator-comprehension` (or whatever it's called) would work too, I have no idea which is most efficient though ...